# Не получается поделиться файлом

Tags: java, android-intent

Пытаюсь поделиться файлом которая делает моя программа и у меня не получается.

Код с помощью которого отправляю файл:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(),"workbook.xlsx");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(file));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"ASDASD"));
```

Вылезает вот такая ошибка

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.testingapp.myapplication, PID: 3270
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:473)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7892)
> at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16219)
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7869)
> at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30880)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7892) 
> at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16219) 
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213) 
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7869) 
> at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30880) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067) 
> Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/com.testingapp.myapplication/files/workbook.xlsx exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
> at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:2208)
> at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2407)
> at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:1088)
> at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:12516)
> at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:12525)
> at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:12501)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1800)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5596)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:780)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5554)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:761)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6052)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6019)
> at com.testingapp.myapplication.MainActivity.ShareFile(MainActivity.java:168)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7892) 
> at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16219) 
> at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213) 
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7869) 
> at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30880) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

Как сделать так, чтобы я мог делиться этим файлом?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: В "такая ошибка" даже нет ошибки, а только ее причина. Нужно читать (и цитировать) весь текст, а не только одно случайное предложение.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException